# How to avoid validation when user submit the section of InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

How to create a validation rule when user want to submit their item in each sections based on checking the fields.

> NB : Each section has two required fields.

Comment: Is there any condition which you apply for displaying and hiding your sections ?

Comment: Thanks Youssef for prompt respond. I have 3 radio button(New,Current and Reject).  When User select the fist new button, it will display the first section . The rest are hidden.

Comment: You are welcome @Sara, so you need to apply a **Validation rule** for your first required fields they will have **Is not blank** and for the second required fields they will have a validation rule with **Is blank** **AND** (New is true) **OR** **Is not blank** **AND** (Current is true) let me know if it works or not.